# Why wont this code run?

Tags: java

Ultra java noob here, I am sure its probably a silly mistake. Some care to correct me?

```
public class Test1 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
int n = 4;

public void f(int n){
 System.out.print(n);
 if(n<=1)
  return;
  else{
      f(n/2);
      f(n/2);
      }
   }
 }
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
Uncompilable source code - illegal start of expression at the
public void f(int n)
```

Comment: Because you have a syntax error, which the compiler should tell you about when you try to compile it.

Comment: its pointing to the method i am trying to run...  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - illegal start of expression at the public void f(int n) line

Comment: Hint:  Count the number of `{` characters and the number of `}` characters.  They should be the same.

Comment: Don't skip braces because you can - _always_ use braces. Hence, add a pair to the first part of your `if` clause. It makes for more readable code. Also, you're indentation is uneven - ensure every `{` aligns with its corresponding `}`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot declare methods within methods in Java. You're missing a `}` somewhere before `public void f(int n)`.

Answer (score 3):

The structure needs to be a bit different, try this approach:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        f(4);
    }

    public static void f(final int n) {
        System.out.print(n);
        if (n <= 1) {
            return;
        } else {
            f(n / 2);
            f(n / 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // TODO code application logic here
    int n = 4;

    f(n);  
}

public void f(int n)
{
    System.out.print(n);

    if( n <= 1)
    {
      return;
    }
    else
    {
        f(n/2);
    }
}
```

Comment: that gives me an error, however if i change it to a static method then its okay... any reason why?

Comment: Because to use the `f` method you must instantiate an instance of the class that declares it. Making it `static` there's no need for that.

Comment: Yes, because there's no instance.

Answer (score 0):

Because for compiler your code looks like this

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 4;


        public void f(int n) {
            System.out.print(n);
            if (n <= 1)
                return;
            else {
                f(n / 2);
                f(n / 2);
            }
        }
    }
```

so it has 2 errors

1) you are trying to create method in method (`f` inside `main`)

2) no `}` at the end of class